# jquery validation date format issues in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-formatting

im using jquery validation and have a date field, using jquery i applay the datepicker to the edit field:

HTML:

```
        <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.rol.fecha_expiracion, new { @id = "AdmPermfechaHastaNuevoRol" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.rol.fecha_expiracion)
```

script:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#AdmPermfechaHastaNuevoRol").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: 0
    });
});
```

now im from argentina, and i need to format my date fields, so i have a script to change the datepiker format:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '<Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig>',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
});
```

the problem im having is that when i use jqueryu validate on my form using chrome, and try to post the form i get a validation error (jquery validation error) that says somthing like "fecha_expiracion ust be a date"

as u can see from the datepiker config script i format my date like:`'dd/mm/yy'`

and that is the problem, if the date i put is somthing like 10/5/2012 is ok, but if i put 25/5/2012 BUM!!! so i guess is trying to parse to json  the date like `mm/dd/yy`, does any know how to fix this? any ideas or directions? tks

EDIT: 
i try this
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/579279/Fixing-jQuery-non-US-Date-Validation-for-Chrome
only get this:

> ncaught RangeError: Invalid language tag: 24/07/2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a similar [problem description](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-with-date-validation-fails-in-webkit-browsers) and a [workaround](http://xilith.com/datepicker/).

Optionally, you can use the jQueryUI Datepicker validation plugin.